# youtube GeolocationSearch Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: youtube

I downloaded several samples from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

The **search.java**, **UpdateVideo.java** can run successfully, which means I have applied `youtube.apikey`, `client_secret` and `client_id` successfully, or these two code will fail to run. But when I run **GeolocaionSearch.java**, it always shows me

> There was a service error: 403 : Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use
>   Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

When I run

```
VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();
```

and the line before this line

```
YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet, recordingDetails").setId(videoId);
```

can run successfully and I can get the video id.

I don't know why it shows me the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is the right answer:
YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet").setId(videoId);
          listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
          VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

Comment: any reasons why they have missed this line in the GeolocationSearch class?